# Magento extension giving problem at time of install

Tags: magento

I am using extension in magento "J2TRememberMe", but at installation it's giving me problems. It's showing a message like:

```
"Failed to download magento-community/J2TRememberMe within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 1.0, stability "beta", use "channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/community/J2TRememberMe-1.0" to install

Cannot initialize 'channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/community/J2TRememberMe', invalid or missing package file

Install Errors
Package "channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/community/J2TRememberMe" is not valid
PEAR ERROR: install failed"
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the tab settings, change the preferred state from "stable" to "beta"

Answer (score 0):

Magento Connect uses PEAR on the backend.  PEAR is a package management system for PHP that grew out of the PHP Code repository of the same name.  Try using the key

```
community/J2TRememberMe-1.0
```

to install your module.  Module Keys look to be PEAR URIs.

Comment: I have tried ...now its giving error like "Invalid package identifier provided: community/J2TRememberMe-1.0 "